# Where to download skype 4.2.0.13

Tags: linux, centos, skype

I installed latest skype to my centos 7.1 box however there is only virtual devices. The problem is described here http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/After-4-3-0-37-the-divices-only-show-up-as-quot-virtual-device/td-p/3228886 People say they can use 4.2.0.13 however I can't find where to download it from. At official site - only latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens to you is most likely because you don't have [Pulseaudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio) running. Skype versions prior to 4.3 allowed to use [ALSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) directly but this is not the case any more. Microsoft have [dropped the support for ALSA](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/No-sound-with-ALSA-after-recent-Skype-upgrade-4-2-gt-4-3-on/td-p/3219164) since version 4.3. You skype client only shows virtual devices, because it does not detect an instance of Pulseaudio running and cannot gain access to your audio devices.

The forum you have pointed to has outdated information. Downgrading to a version lower than 4.3 will not solve the problem.

After dropping ALSA support, including a number of vulnaribilities and introducing a [backdoor](http://www.technobuffalo.com/2013/07/11/microsoft-gave-the-nsa-direct-backdoor-access-to-outlook-skype/) into the Skype protocol Microsoft realized that significant number of users are downgrading their clients. Having realized that Microsoft started blocking the login attempts for clients with version lower than 4.3

If you want to continue to use skype you will have to upgrade to the newest version and either use Pulseaudio or try one of the known workarounds like [apulse](https://github.com/i-rinat/apulse).

FYI:

- http://www.telecomstechnews.com/news/2014/aug/08/why-is-skype-forcing-a-software-upgrade-on-all-of-us-plus-the-community-outrage/
- [Skype 4.3 without PulseAudio, only ALSA. Any options?](https://superuser.com/q/808774/281154)

Comment: You are right. yum install pulseaudio-libs.i686 alsa-plugins-pulseaudio.i686 Helped me - (skype works only with 32 but centos 7 is only 64)

Answer (score 2):

Download [this](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/sourceforge/s/sn/snowbird/yum/sb20/skype-4.2.0.13-1.fc20.i686.html) and then `cd` into your downloads directory, then type `sudo yum install skype-4.2.0.13-1.fc20.i686.rpm` and it should be OK.

Comment: Incorrect. You will not be able to login with skype v < 4.3 because Microsoft has purposely made it incompatible and blocks all login attempts with older versions

Comment: Yes, but OP wanted to download this version.

Comment: Valid point. This answers the question bud does not solve the problem